# Syncing Google Calendar [Gcal] and Emacs Org-mode? Is it possible?

Tags: emacs, google-calendar, org-mode

It would be amazing if I could sync Gcal and emacs org-mode, is it possible?

Comment: It's emacs, OF COURSE it's possible! Likewise, it's Google, OF COURSE it's possible! Granted, I have no idea how to DO it, but I'm positive that it can be done. (Sorry to not be helpful)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-google-sync.html and see if this is good enough for you...

Answer (score 5):

In case more people come back to this question during the next years: since summer 2011 there is a really great solution:

https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw

Comment: This is a really good extension to emacs for viewing calendar information and runs on top of google calendar & org. Can show events from both in one view but I don't think it pulls the data from iCalendar source into an org-mode file.

Comment: Calfw seems to be an Emacs package which allows you to *view* any of Emacs diary, org-mode, .ics, and something called howm. But as koushik states, I don't think there's any effective conversion between these.

Answer (score 3):

Michael Hall made me laugh with his [rant](http://mph.puddingbowl.org/2010/02/org-mode-in-your-pocket-is-a-gnu-shaped-devil/) on his ambivalent love-affair with the joyous rabbit-hole called org-mode, and being seduced back into it (after escaping into iPhone) by the new MobileOrg app.  In that rant he mentions that back in 2007, [Bill Clementson](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070306.html) had managed to hack a certain "Emacs client for Google Services" by T.V. Raman (of emacspeak fame), which allowed him (Clementson) to sync his emacs diary appointments with his Google Calendar / GCal on the fly.  Perhaps you or someone could do the same with it but for org-mode? (I would like to but I am years off in my e-lisp knowledge.)

Answer (score 3):

Recently a project called [org-gcal](https://github.com/myuhe/org-gcal.el) appeared and it might fit your requirements.
Its Web page describes a step-by-step procedure to setup org-mode in order to support bidirectional sync between Google calendar and a org file, on the basis of a calendar by file. In summary org-gcal offers:

- Fetch google calendar event
- Post/edit org element

All the requirements are managed using the built-in package manager for Emacs 24+. The project is hosted on the MELPA repository for easy install.

The author implemented as feature a sync-and-close file procedure. It might be a little disturbing at the beginning because after a sync (`org-gcal-fetch`) or create a new event (`org-gcal-post-at-point`) the buffer is closed but you can notice by reopening it or navigating in the org-agenda-mode that tasks are updated in both senses.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Can you give more detail in your answer. Have you used this application before and what are its key features? Thanks

Comment: It seems like this only posts/edits certain parts (where `point` is). Can it be used to agenda-wise entries? Export all agenda entries to the google calendar?

Comment: You can sync a complete calendar from google to org. However you can only sync from org to google posting at point. I suppose the logic behind this procedure is to add incrementally appointments to the agenda but it is not designed to add an agenda as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this website apart from its more sync calendar rather than Org-Mode.

http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070306.html

I havn't tested it yet because it didn't work the first time I tried and I couldn't be bothered to find out why. Perhaps it was simply a typo, anyhoo, I hope you have more luck than me.

or theres this thread that talks about orgmode and gcal.
http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg03398.html

but not sure if there is a method, at least there is no out of the box method with org-mode as of yet.